# How to convert xml to json in angular 4?

Tags: xml, angular

Am a beginner in angular 4, I don't have enough knowledge how to handle XML to JSON and how to call Service in angular 4, please suggest

Answer (score 2):

Based on the library http://goessner.net/download/prj/jsonxml/, I implemented a sample to receive XML data and parse them into an Angular4 application:

```
var headers = new Headers();
(...)
headers.append('Accept', 'application/xml');

return this.http.get('https://angular2.apispark.net/v1/companies/', {
  headers: headers
}).map(res => JSON.parse(xml2json(res.text(),'  ')));
```

To be able to use the library, you need to parse first the XML string:

```
var parseXml;

if (typeof window.DOMParser != "undefined") {
  parseXml = function(xmlStr) {
    return ( new window.DOMParser() ).parseFromString(xmlStr, "text/xml");
  };
} else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject != "undefined" &&
   new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")) {
    parseXml = function(xmlStr) {
      var xmlDoc = new window.ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
      xmlDoc.async = "false";
      xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlStr);
      return xmlDoc;
  };
} else {
  throw new Error("No XML parser found");
}
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/dj63ASQAgrNcLLlwyAum?p=preview.

Comment: Thanks. This conversion I got it, still am confusing how to convert in our my ts(typescript) file (example.ts) file.

Comment: No not confusing ,Just show the plunkr example and see you how conver in our ts file

Comment: Very Good! @FerasAlSous